# f.select onchange , pass this.value to a ruby variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have got this line of code in form:
 f.select(:SUB_ASSAY_TYPE, @types, {:prompt => 'Select the Type'}, {:onChange => "alert(this.value)}) %>

What i want to do is to assign the 'this.value' to a ruby variable on onchange event like shown below:
{:onChange => "alert(this.value); @rubyvar = (this.value)" }

I know that's not how it should be done but i have no idea how to do this in ajax or using remote function.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: what do you hope to accomplish by changing the value of a ruby variable? I can't imagine how this would be useful. If you can explain what you're trying to accomplish a little better, perhaps I can try to demonstrate how to use an AJAX call to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set a ruby variable from the client, since its evaluated on your server.

What you need is an Ajax call which renders some new javascript to the client.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your help. I wanted to read the 'this.value' and assign it to a ruby variable and based on that variable, i was going to display some hidden div using something like the code below: div id="ISH"  <%= 'style="display: none"' unless @rubyvar == "ISH"  %>>

Comment: However i found another solution to this (don't know whether it's the way to go or not but hey it works!!) What i did is add 'this.value' as a parameter to the url and retrieve that value from the URL to display my div. E.g.<div id="ISH"  <%= 'style="display: none"' unless params[:id2] == "ISH"  %>> I would love to know the ajax way though.

Comment: Well if all you need to do is to show a hidden DIV then I would suggest you trigger a JavaScript callback when the select is changed, something like this: :onchange => "if(this.value == something){$('ISH').show()} else {$('ISH').hide()}; return false" - Warning, untested code... :)